# win 10 network drive mapping to wrong letter

Tags: windows-10, network-shares

After upgrading a windows 10 computer one network drive does not mount correctly. We have two network mounts, one at G: and another at S:

After upgrading to win 10 the network folder mapped to S: is mapped correctly but the one mapped to G: does not get mapped correctly. When I go to File Explorer then I see the G: but it has a red cross over it and if I click it I get a popup with title `Location is not Available` and main text `G:\ is not accessible. The device is not ready`.

The network drives are mounted using a domain group policy executed at logon, its a .cmd file that contains two lines of `net use g: \\servername\shared_folder_name` the other line uses s: instead of g: but after a short time when the user logs on (doesn´t matter what user it is) then the folder gets mapped under a different drive letter, namely z: (and this breaks a lot of short cuts so getting it mapped correctly is important).

On the client computer I can not delete the G: using `net use g: /delete` that just gives me `The network connection could not be found.` neither can I remap the network folder from z: to g:. Issuing just `net use` shows just s: and z: in use. Other computers that have not upgraded to win 10 have no issue with this and the drives get mapped correctly.

So I am at a loss here, any ideas?

EDIT: I disabled offline files and restarted the computer. Now the G: drive letter no longer shows up in File Explorer (the network folder still maps under Z) and if I try `net use g: \\server\folder` then I get `System error 85 has occured` and `The local device name is already in use` but I can't see any device associated with the letter G.

EDIT2: Looking in regedit under HKLM/System/MountedDevices then I see the G letter in use there, and I suspect that it is either a USB driver or a SD card reader. How can I know which one it is? And how can I tell win 10 to stop using the drive letter G for USB or SD card reader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to Disk Management I found the drive letter there, I reassigned it to H: rebooted the machine and then it worked fine. Seems to have been either a USB or SD Card reader.